# Y-axis to be inverted

Tags: javascript, html, css, two.js

I am using two.js library in javascript to make a system coordinates, and i want  the Y-axis to be inverted. Now 0,0 is at the top left but I want it to be at the bottom left

Answer (score 3):

```
var two = new Two({
  fullscreen: true,
  autostart: true
}).appendTo(document.body);

two.scene._matrix.manual = true;
two.scene._matrix.translate(0, two.height).scale(1, -1);

var rect = two.makeRectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);
var circ = two.makeCircle(0, 50, 25);
```

Comment: In the latest version you can now set the scale of a shape to a vector. E.g instead of `manual = true;` you can just do: `two.scene.scale = new Two.Vector( 1 - 1 );` and `two.scene.translation.set( 0, two.height );`

Answer (score -1):

```
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,100]).range([0,300]);
console.log( y(0), y(50), y(100) );
//-> [0, 150, 300]

var y2 = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,100]).range([450,150]);
console.log( y2(0), y2(50), y2(100) );
//-> [450, 300, 150]
```

The first example maps increasing x to increasing y, which is not what you wanted. The second one maps increasing x to decreasing y. (It also `offsets x=100 to y=150,` in case you needed padding.)

Another one answer:

I recommend using an inverted range for the y-scale, so that it always
encodes position:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([minValue, maxValue])
      .range([height, 0]);
```

When you compute the "y" attribute of a rect, you can use the y-scale
directly. For the height attribute, you'll have to use height - y(d),
but that seems reasonable to me. When you use an inverted range this
way, you can also use the scale with a d3.svg.axis, and it will do the
right thing.

Comment: Initially I almost was about to answer similarly. The solution you suggest is quite correct with respect to d3 library. Wonder if the implementation is same for 'two.js'

Comment: So how this code can be used with 'two.js' library?